# make NestWhileList faster without compile

Tags: function-construction

this is the function, that generates list of aliquots of numbers, it's fine for those which have short lists but for longer ones it takes its time

```
alseqom[n_] := 
 NestWhileList[Total[Most[Divisors[#]]] &, n, 
  And[ UnsameQ[##], Last[{##}] > 0] &, {2, 4}, 550, -1]
```

I had to put limit of 550 elements to avoid hanging    same as to exclude repetitions..

Comment: Why without compile?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher well compile is computer and software work, I pretend to arrive to efficient writing functions, faster or with less memory or both ... I had used NestWhileList ... maybe this is not as efficient as some Apply   or Map   or .... this is what I would like to know ... learn from more expereienced users

Comment: Are you more interested into the values for a few `n` or for a whole range of them like 1 to 10000 or so? This may be important for the choice of tools...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  most numbers I found in a function taken from http://oeis.org/A126016  some of them take huge time, as 276  or 306 and finally arrive to bigger and bigger values ... whose prime decomposition is I think the bottle-neck ...

Comment: Yes, I think you are absolutely right. The bottleneck is `Divisors`; it can easily take several seconds for a single number with about 67 digits... I am afraid, we cannot di much about it =o/